# Why isn't Jupyter notebook running from VBA?

Tags: python, vba, ms-access, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run a Jupyter notebook from Access VBA:

```
Sub import_hawk()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String

    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    PythonExe = """C:\Users\Philip\.conda\envs\latest\python.exe"""
    PythonScript = "C:\Users\Philip\OneDrive\Betting\Capra\Tennis\polgara\polgara.ipynb"

    objShell.run PythonExe & PythonScript

End Sub
```

When I run it then a box does briefly appear and then disappears. I've run the notebook manually and it works fine. The most frustrating thing is that it was working for about 5 mins and now isn't...

Comment: Aren't you supposed to run the notebook with `jupyter notebook <notebook>`?

Comment: You're also not providing a space between PythonExe and PythonScript

Comment: @michalwa - afraid I'm quite new at this - where does that go in the VBA?

Comment: @ErikA - added the space to no avail :(

Comment: Replace the path to python with `jupyter notebook `, where jupyter can be replaced by the full path to jupyter.

Comment: I've only ever used Jupyter by launching from Anaconda or more recently through VS Code. I've searched for Jupyter and this was the only result: ```C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\Jupyter Notebook (Anaconda3)```. When I go to the location of the shortcut then it highlights a ```python.exe``` file in ```C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3```. I've tried ```C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe notebook``` but the ```objShell.run``` line fails. I've tried ```C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe```and a box appears but no end product (same as before)

Comment: After a little more investigation I've found that if I only run ```PythonExe``` then I get a command line window open and the following message come up ```This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.``` I guess this is the issue but I can't for life of me work out how to activate an environment through VBA...

Comment: Been trying to work through this for hours now. I now understand about environment variables and have added ```Anaconda3\Scripts```. I also wasn't wedded to using a Jupyter Notebook so switching to a ```.py``` file has got me to the point where if I enter ```activate [myenv]``` into the command line and then ```C:\Users\Philip\.conda\envs\capra\python.exe C:\Users\Philip\OneDrive\Betting\Capra\Tennis\polgara\polgara.py``` then the script runs! However, if I put them both together in one big long string then I get ```activate does not accept more than one argument:```. What should I do?

Comment: Getting there!! ```activate capra & C:\Users\Philip\.conda\envs\capra\python.exe C:\Users\Philip\OneDrive\Betting\Capra\Tennis\polgara\polgara.py``` runs the script in the right environment!! Might just have enough energy left to figure out how to run the Jupyter Notebook...

Comment: Well I'm totally stumped now. The script in my last comment works fine if I paste it into the command line and run it. However, it won't run in the procedure from my original post: ```objShell.run "activate capra & C:\Users\Philip\.conda\envs\capra\python.exe C:\Users\Philip\OneDrive\Betting\Capra\Tennis\polgara\polgara.py"```. I get a ```Method 'Run' of object 'IWshShell3' failed``` error. Any ideas?

Comment: Tried 20+ variations of the string - nothing works. Couple of interesting results. 1. ```activate capra``` on its own fails in the same way as above.  2. ```cmd /k activate capra``` gives ```'activate' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.``` in the command line window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I have put square brackets where other people would need to put their specific info:

```
Sub execute_notebook()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim new_cmd_window              As String
Dim full_script                 As String
Dim activate_env                As String
Dim change_dir_script           As String
Dim convert_and_run_nb          As String

Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

new_cmd_window = "cmd /c"
activate_env = "cd /d [path to Anaconda\Scripts folder which on my machine is C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts] & activate [environment_name] &"
change_dir_notebook = "cd /d [path to folder where notebook is] &"
convert_and_run_nb = "jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute [notebook name].ipynb"
full_script = new_cmd_window & " " & Chr(34) & activate_env & " " & change_dir_script & " " & convert_and_run_nb & Chr(34)

objShell.run full_script

End Sub
```

Couple of notes on my findings:

1. Didn't work without `new_cmd_window`
2. For some reason simply using `activate [environment name]` wouldn't work from VBA. Was fine when I typed it into the cmd line. In the end I had to manually change the directory and run it that way.