# How to execute ipynb file in excel VBA code

Tags: python-3.x, vba, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to execute some python scripts through VBA code.

**.py** files are working pretty well, but i am struggling with **.ipynb** files

running python script(.py) as following link :

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73258152/how-to-exceute-ipynb-file-in-excel-vba-code),

but the same way doesn't work for **ipynb** files.

After quite long searching, i found this article

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/62657958/19118788

and in this article, below code is suggested to run **ipynb** file in excel VBA.

```
    Sub execute_notebook()

       Dim objShell As Object
       Dim new_cmd_window              As String
       Dim full_script                 As String
       Dim activate_env                As String
       Dim change_dir_script           As String
       Dim convert_and_run_nb          As String

       Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

       new_cmd_window = "cmd /c"
       activate_env = "cd /d [path to Anaconda\Scripts folder which on my machine is                                    
       C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts] & activate [environment_name] &"
       change_dir_notebook = "cd /d [path to folder where notebook is] &"
       convert_and_run_nb = "jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute [notebook name].ipynb"
       full_script = new_cmd_window & " " & Chr(34) & activate_env & " " & change_dir_script & " " & convert_and_run_nb & Chr(34)

       objShell.run full_script

    End Sub
```

Most of lines are understood, but i have no idea for **[environment_name]** in the above code.

(I am beginner to these things)

**Please tell me, what should i do for [environment_name] ??**

Comment: I guess it is the name of a virtual environment that you must [create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment) before that command.

Comment: the script you posted is using conda to manage the environments, check out conda's docs: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html